# MySQL gets corrupted variable after a RETURN SELECT Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I have a database with a field TEXT, where is stored a JSON string.
This database is UTF-8 and when I select the JSON field, with a normal select, I read a correct JSON, like as stored.
BUT, in a Stored Procedure, I read the field to a variable, and then, the variable gets corrupted after a SELECT.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_G;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_G(
    OUT eCode           CHAR(5),
    OUT eDescription    TEXT,
    IN  uID             INT UNSIGNED
    )
BEGIN
    DECLARE other_right         TEXT;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            eCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, eDescription = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    SET eCode='00000';
    SET eDescription='';

    SET other_right         = "";

    -- (...code...)
    SELECT y
    INTO other_right
    FROM X
    WHERE z=1
    -- (...code...)

    CALL SP_SaveVariableContent_to_test(other_right)
    -- IN THIS PLACE other_right is OK 
    SELECT other_right;
    CALL SP_SaveVariableContent_to_test(other_right)
    -- IN THIS PLACE other_right is WRONG
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

FIELD CONTENT:
[image: Correct Content]

CURRUPT CONTENT AFTER A SELECT:
[image]

> UPDATED: This stored procedure is only for tests, 'printing' the
>   content of a variable

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SaveVariableContent_to_test(IN  description         TEXT)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tmp_prints(description) values(description);
END
```

Comment: No, outside of the Stored Procedure, the value is correct. Only the SELECT inside the stored procedure is wrong.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL? MySQLi? MariaDB? only tag the product you are using

Comment: i think you have stripped out too much in your code for it to make sense. your code snippet does nothing at all in its current form

Comment: what is inside `SP_SaveVariableContent_to_test(other_right)` ?

Comment: Updated: SP_SaveVariableContent_to_test is only to 'print' the content of a variable, this do a INSERT to a 'log table'

Comment: Please take some time to ready ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as at this point there is too little information to assist you

Comment: Can you provide the bad & good strings in machine-readable format, not just .png?

Comment: Please do `SELECT HEX(...)` of the bad text.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved

I solve it, changing return value from SELECT to a OUTPUT parameter.
Like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_G;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_G(
    OUT eCode           CHAR(5),
    OUT eDescription    TEXT,
    IN  uID             INT UNSIGNED,
    OUT other_right     TEXT
    )
BEGIN
    -- [DISABLED] DECLARE other_right           TEXT; [DISABLED]
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            eCode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, eDescription = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    
    SET eCode='00000';
    SET eDescription='';
    
    SET other_right         = "";

    -- (...code...)
    SELECT y
    INTO other_right
    FROM X
    WHERE z=1
    -- (...code...)

    CALL SP_SaveVariableContent_to_test(other_right)
    -- IN THIS PLACE other_right is OK 
    -- [DISABLE] SELECT other_right; [DISABLE]
    CALL SP_SaveVariableContent_to_test(other_right)
    -- IN THIS PLACE other_right is OK too :D
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

I think that this is a MySQL bug, I use CentOS with MariaDB 10.1